# Powerautomate remove word from string

Tags: power-automate

Afternoon,

Apologies if this has been answered but i've looked around and couldn't find a answer.
I have a MS form which uploads files but after the file name it adds _anonymous
e.g instead of picture.jpg its picture_anonymous.jpg

I'm looking for a way to remove the "_anonymous" keeping the original filename and extention.

I know it can be done with the expressions but its not something im used to.

Thanks

various expressions but its not my strong suit

Comment: have you tried splitting and renaming it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a couple of expressions in a Move or Rename file action (assuming that the files from the MS Forms question get stored on the OneDrive).

Below is an example 
*Make sure you replace my question id by your specific question id*

1.Add a Move or Rename file action directly after the Get response details
a.Use the expression below to retrieve the file identifier:

```
first(json(outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/red0589afa18d4cf9904ce51ad931c81a']))['id']
```

b.Use the expression below to replace the _anonymous string by nothing, which will remove it

```
replace(first(json(outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/red0589afa18d4cf9904ce51ad931c81a']))['name'], '_anonymous', '')
```

[image]